# PostgreSQL: Using different columns in select and group by does not cause error

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

So, I was learning about ***windows functions*** from here, https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/

Before the section for window functions start, there is a brief introduction to the ***aggregate functions*** and ***group by*** clause.

These are the reference tables I am using as per the tutorial:

[image]
[image]

As far as I understand, one is supposed to use the same field in ***SELECT*** and ***GROUP BY*** clause. e.g.

```
SELECT p.group_id, avg(p.price)  from PRODUCTS p GROUP BY p.group_id;
```

Otherwise, PostgreSQL will give out an error:
`column "" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.`

But, I am bit confused by the results of the below query:

`select group_name,avg(price) from product_groups inner join products p using (group_id) group by group_id;`

First of all, I am using different columns in select and group by i.e. `group_name` and `group_id` respectively. But, it does not throw an error similar to above!

And, it gives the following result. It looks like `group_name` and `group_id` are being used interchangeably here. Could any please explain what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: What constraints are there on those tables? In particular, are there any constraints that might tell Postgres that if the group_id:s are the same, then the group_names will be the same, too?

Comment: There are no such constraints. I am using the queries given in this tutorial: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the rules for `GROUP BY` are *almost* complete.  In general, whatever columns appear in the `SELECT` clause also have to appear in `GROUP BY`.  However, there is an exception in the ANSI standard, which states that if a column in `GROUP BY` which *uniquely* determines the values of other columns, then those other columns can also appear in the `SELECT` clause.

Having a closer look at your second query:

```sql
SELECT group_name, AVG(price)           -- valid, because if we know
FROM product_groups                     -- group_id then we also know
INNER JOIN products p USING (group_id)  -- group_name
GROUP BY group_id;
```

In the `products` table, if `group_id` is either the primary key or otherwise a unique key, then if we pick a certain value for `group_id`, we also know uniquely what the `group_name` would be.  If so, then technically your second query is ANSI compliant.  Postgres, more than most other databases, tends to closely follow the ANSI standard, so it accepts your query as being valid.